# delay in downloading image from server with volley

Tags: android, download, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I try to downloading image from server with volley and show them in recyclerview.
it is work correctly but the downloading image is very low.
(the size of each image approximately 50 kb).
what can i do?
is there better and optimize code than it?

this is my helper class:

```
public class StartActivity {

  // for recyclerView - downLoad Data
  private static final int LIMIT = 6;
  OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
  int idImage = 1;
  private List<StructUser> structList = new ArrayList<>();
  private AdapterUser adapter;
  private int CURRENT_ITEM = 1;
  private Context context;
  private String TAG = StartActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  //----------------------------------------------------
  public StartActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public void getDataAndSetInRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    loadData(CURRENT_ITEM);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

    adapter = new AdapterUser(recyclerView, structList, context);


    onLoadMoreListener = new OnLoadMoreListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLoadMore() {

        structList.add(null);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            structList.remove(structList.size() - 1);
//            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(structList.size());
            loadData(CURRENT_ITEM);
          }
        }, 2000);

      }
    };

    adapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(onLoadMoreListener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private void loadData(final int CURRENT_ITEM) {
    String url = Config.DATA_URL + CURRENT_ITEM;
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
      new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
          ActivityMain.hideProgressBar();
          try {


            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
              StructUser structUser = new StructUser();


              if (!jsonObject.isNull(Config.TAG_TITLE))
                structUser.setNetworkImageView(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_TITLE));
              if (!jsonObject.isNull(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL)) {
                structUser.setNetworkImageView(Config.IMG_SERVER + idImage + ".png");
                idImage++;
              }
              structList.add(structUser);


            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            adapter.setLoaded();

            // not show progressBar at end of list when get all data

            if (response.toString().contains("[]")) {
              adapter.reachEndList();
              Toast.makeText(context, "not More Data to Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // hide progressBar
        ActivityMain.hideProgressBar();

        Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context,
          error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest, TAG);
    this.CURRENT_ITEM = this.CURRENT_ITEM + LIMIT;
  }


}
```

this is my adapter:

```
public class AdapterUser extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
  private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
  public int visibleThreshold = 2;
  boolean isLoading;
  private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
  private List<StructUser> structList = new ArrayList<>();
  private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;
  private Context context;

  // load image from server -------------------------------------------------
  private static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
  public static DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnLoading(R.mipmap.ic_cloud_download)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.ic_picture)
    .showImageOnFail(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisk(false)
    .considerExifParams(true)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();
  //---------------------------------------------------------------


  public AdapterUser(RecyclerView mRecyclerView, List<StructUser> structList, Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    this.structList = structList;
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
      @Override
      public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();



        if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= visibleThreshold + (lastVisibleItem)) {
          if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
            mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
          }
          isLoading = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }


  public void setLoaded() {
    isLoading = false;
  }

  public void reachEndList() {
    isLoading = true;
  }

  //========================================================
  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return structList.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_start_activity , viewGroup, false);
      return new UserViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_item, viewGroup, false);
      return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof UserViewHolder) {
      UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
      StructUser user = structList.get(position);
      userViewHolder.title.setText(user.getTitle());

// load image from server
      imageLoader.displayImage(user.getNetworkImageView(), userViewHolder.networkImageView, options);




    } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
      LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
      loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return structList == null ? 0 : structList.size();
  }

  public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
    this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
  }


  class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    // for download & cash image
    public ImageView networkImageView;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
      networkImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

    }
  }

  class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    }

  }



}
```

Comment: I would consider using Picasso or Glide lib. (and if the images will not change, use cache for the downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide for downloading Image...

```
Glide.with(ActivityName.this)
.load(image_url)
.into(imageView_object);
```

It will download image and set in ImageView.

Comment: don't use that..Use Glide library for image loading.It is very easy